# What is the difference between below code snippets?

Tags: ios, swift

```
class AGResults: Codable {
let geoFencing: [ActiveGeoFencingArray]

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case geoFencing = "geo_fencing"
}

init(geoFencing: [ActiveGeoFencingArray]) {
    self.geoFencing = geoFencing
}}
```

And

```
typealias AGResults = [ActiveGeoFencingArray]
```

If I use Class then it gives error while decoding:

```
let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: geoFencingDic, options: .prettyPrinted)
let activeGeoFences = try newJSONDecoder().decode(AGResults.self, from: jsonData)
```

Error:

```
▿ DecodingError
  ▿ typeMismatch : 2 elements
    - .0 : Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>
    ▿ .1 : Context
      - codingPath : 0 elements
      - debugDescription : "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead."
      - underlyingError : nil
```

If I use typealias then it works fine.

What is the difference between these two approch?

Comment: It's like a a commodity "renaming". In your case, I would keep the class.

Comment: Check out the [Swift language guide](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Declarations.html) for a good explanation for "Type Alias Declaration"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the class named `AGResults` then your json should have a root property called `geo_fencing`. If you use the typealias named `AGResults` instead, the decoder expects to decode an array.

A typealias is exactly that - an alias. So by doing this:

```
typealias AGResults = [ActiveGeoFencingArray]
```

you are telling the compiler that `AGResults` equals `[ActiveGeoFencingArray]`, basically meaning that whenever you use `AGResults` in your code you are actually referring to `[ActiveGeoFencingArray]`

Answer (score 0):

A typealias is just a shorthand. It doesn't actually do anything other than let you use the new alias in place of whatever it is defined as.

A class is a definition of a custom object type. You have to instantiate instances of a class in order to use it.